# Update each wind rose's properties in a python plotly subplot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to plot multiple wind roses in a subplot using Barplot function of the plotly.graph_objects library. I have succeded to render the wind roses.

After that, I tried to customize the properties of the wind roses using fig.update_layout, but only one of them was updated properly (see figure).
'''

```
fig.update_layout(
    title=title,
    title_font_size=26,
    title_x = 0.463,
    legend_font_size=18,
    polar_radialaxis_ticksuffix='%',
    polar_angularaxis_rotation=90,
    polar_angularaxis_direction='clockwise',
    polar_angularaxis_tickmode = 'array',
    polar_angularaxis_tickvals=[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315],
    polar_angularaxis_ticktext=['<b>N</b>','NE', '<b>E</b>', 'SE', '<b>S</b>', 'SW', '<b>W</b>', 'NW'],
    polar_angularaxis_tickfont_size = 22,
    polar_radialaxis_tickmode = 'linear',
    polar_radialaxis_angle = 45,
    polar_radialaxis_tick0 = 5,
    polar_radialaxis_dtick = 5,
    polar_radialaxis_tickangle = 100,
    polar_radialaxis_tickfont_size = 14)
```

'''
[image]
Can anyone please suggest some way to achieve this ? the main properties I want to modify (polar_angularaxis_rotation polar_angularaxis_direction , polar_angularaxis_tickvals , polar_angularaxis_ticktext … )